# RSA rainbow table

Tags: rsa, rainbow-table

Wouldn't it be possible to create as many as possible key pairs for the RSA encryption and then determine from a public key which the corresponding private key is ?

Comment: Short answer: No, there are too many possible key pairs.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to your question is very closely related to this post:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263588/how-many-all-prime-numbers-p-with-length-of-bits-of-p-1024-bits

Via. the prime number theorem we can calculate that there are approximately 1.26 * 10<sup>305</sup> prime numbers less than 2<sup>1024</sup>. That is *a lot* of numbers. For scale, a terabyte is 10<sup>12</sup> bytes!

So yes, though this brute force approach is theoretically doable we don't, and won't, have the resources for a very long time!

Comment: replace "for a very long time" with "it's physically impossible!" as per [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1160/23623)

Comment: @SEJPM Currently believed to be physically impossible would be more accurate. Once upon a time, heavier than air flying machines were physically impossible.